# Executing a python script

Tags: python-3.4

I am a biologist trying to run a particular script (http://www.ricediversity.org/tools/code/Plumage%20Script%202%20F2%20Populations.zip) on my data-set. I have installed python 3.4, panda 0.14.0 and numpy dependecies on my windows 7 laptop as the instructions demand. My data set is in excel file. How do I go forth applying this script to my data? I have no experience with python scripts/ program.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
python Plumage2_for_F2.py -h
```

should give you the usage information. (Being on Windows, simply invoking as `Plumage2_for_F2.py` does not work as it would on a Unixoid system, so be sure to preface all your commands with `python`, as above.) The file (as supplied by the `-i` option) will have to be a CSV (comma-separated values), which you can export from Excel (I do not know the current version of Excel, but it should be something like Save As, or Export).